# Remove a button from a custom UITableViewCell after deleting the data from it

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that also holds a custom `UIButton` as a subview. The button shows another image, dependent on the `UITableViewCell.textLabel.text`-data.

When I now remove a row the data gets deleted and moves one up. The problem there is, that the image stays. So, the images are overlaying now. See here

[image]

The image should be either blue or red, not both. Also you can see, that it is a bit thicker. That's because the row gets deleted and the data it contains ( and in the array ) but not the image. I'm using a custom `UITableViewCell` to have a custom swipe to delete. The swipe gesture also lets the user edit data. Not only delete it.

This is the method that gets called, when I press either the delete or edit button

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    switch (index) {
        case 0: {
            //stuff for editing
        }
        case 1:{
            NSString *stringIdentifierTemp  = cell.projectCellIdentifier;
            Firebase *firebaseReferenceTemp = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", stringRequestUrl, stringIdentifierTemp]];
            if ( self.boolFirstTableView ){
                [dictionaryProjects removeObjectForKey:stringIdentifierTemp];
                [firebaseReferenceTemp updateChildValues:@{@"state": @"canceled"}];
            } else {
                [dictionaryFinishedProjects removeObjectForKey:stringIdentifierTemp];
                [firebaseReferenceTemp removeValue];
            }
            [tableView reloadData];
            [tableViewFinished reloadData];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see I remove the data from the `NSMutableDictionary` that holds the data and then reload the tableviews I have. Still, the images are overlaying.

In the method `- (SWTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)realTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, where I define the `UITableViewCells` this is how I add the button

```
CustomButton *stateButton           = [CustomButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    stateButton.projectButtonIdentifier = tempIdentifier;
    stateButton.frame                   = CGRectMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 44.0f, 44.0f);
    [stateButton setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
    [stateButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
    [stateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(updateState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    Firebase *tempRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", stringRequestUrl, tempIdentifier]];
    [tempRef observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        if ( [snapshot.name isEqualToString:@"state"] ) {
            if ( [snapshot.value isEqualToString:@"new"]){
                if ( [important isEqualToString:@"No"] ){
                    [stateButton setBackgroundImage:imageStatusNew forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                } else {
                    [stateButton setBackgroundImage:imageStatusNewRed forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            } else if ( [snapshot.value isEqualToString:@"started"]){
                if ( [important isEqualToString:@"No"] ){
                    [stateButton setBackgroundImage:imageStatusStarted forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                } else {
                    [stateButton setBackgroundImage:imageStatusStartedRed forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            } else if ( [snapshot.value isEqualToString:@"halfway"]){
                if ( [important isEqualToString:@"No"] ){
                    [stateButton setBackgroundImage:imageStatusHalfway forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                } else {
                    [stateButton setBackgroundImage:imageStatusHalfwayRed forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }
        }
    }];

    [cell addSubview:stateButton];
```

A simple off topic: I know it should be written `cancelled` but I didn't make these. :p

Comment: Use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths also have updated the answer please follow

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was, that I was always using the same `CellIdentifier`. Now I just set it to nil and it worked.

```
SWTableViewCell *cell               = (SWTableViewCell *)[realTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

// Cell
if ( cell == nil ){
    cell = [[SWTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil
                                  containingTableView:realTableView leftUtilityButtons:[self leftButtons] rightUtilityButtons:[self rightButtons]];
    cell.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: By using a `nil` cell identifier, you are not using reusable cells, and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will always return `nil`, so you will be creating a new cell every time.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a cell identifier, cells that are no longer visible get reused to save memory, so the cell returned when dequeueing may have a button already.

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you should remove the button if the cell already has one, you can do this by setting a tag for it:

```
CustomButton *stateButton = ... 
...

stateButton.tag = 12345; // use a tag to identify the button
[[cell viewWithTag:stateButton.tag] removeFromSuperview]; // removes old button if it exists
[cell addSubview:stateButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of deleting the data from from the cell you can delete the whole row.